# How to replace character in capture group with sed

Tags: sed

Given a pattern of the form:

```
a\b\c\d:text\text
```

how can I use sed to output

```
a/b/c/d:text\text
```

that is, given a path using backslashes followed by a colon followed by arbitrary text, how do I replace only the backslashes preceding the colon with forward slashes?

Comment: So, the `a\b\c\d` is just an example? The path (the string to the left of the colon) could be `\a\b` or `e\f\g\h\j\k\l`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ways to do this; here is one:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's_^\([^:]*\)\\_\1/_;t a'
```

Explanation breadcrumbs:

`-e` specifies an editing command.  There are two such commands here.

`:a` defines a label which can be used in "goto" statements.

The `s` command replaces the first backslash on the line with a forward slash, as long as the first backslash occurs before any colon character.

The `t a` command branches to the `:a` label providing a substitution was successfully made with the `s` command.  (Conditional "goto.")

Comment: @Scott, if you check my profile and look at my Sed and Awk answers, you will see that I am sometimes given to *very* verbose explanations.  ([Example.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338806/135943))  But, I don't feel obliged to write those in every instance.  I will add a brief explanation, since you asked; feel free to expand it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` rather than `sed`:

```
awk -v FS=':' -v OFS=':' '{ gsub(/\\/,"/",$1) } { print }'
```

This treats the data as a `:`-delimited record and uses `gsub()` to replace all backslashes with forward slashes in the first field. It then outputs the modified data.

I set both the input field separator (`FS`) and the output field separator (`OFS`) to `:` so that the input is split on the colon and so that the colon is later inserted again when the output happens.

---

If you have the text in a shell variable, you may do this directly in the shell without using any external utilities too:

```
a='a\b\c\d:text\text'
b=${a%%:*}  # the start of the string ("remove the first : and everything after it from $a")
c=${a#*:}   # the end of the string ("remove the first : and everything before it from $a")

a="${b//\\//}:$c"

printf '%s\n' "$a"
```

This code snippet will print the string `a/b/c/d:text\text` in any `sh`-shell that supports the parameter expansion `${parameter//pattern/string}` (an extension to the POSIX standard).

This is more or less mimicking the `awk` code.

Comment: With your Awk script in single quotes as shown, you should not need quadruple backslashing ever.  The shell will not try to interpret or further parse *anything* in single quotes.  Can you double check what happened?

Comment: @Wildcard That's what I thought too. So the reason I'm repeating it 4 times is that I get the wrong results (except with `mawk`). That means that it might be something else other than the shell that requires the extra quoting in `gawk` and `nawk`.

Comment: Ah, digging through the [POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), I see that "all string literals are subject to lexical analysis, which would reduce each pair of `<backslash>` characters to a single `<backslash>` before being passed to **gsub**."  So you're running into this because you're passing a *string literal* as a pattern rather than a literal ERE.  Using `gsub(/\\/,"/",$1)` should work on any Awk.  (I'd love it if you could verify; I don't have all those versions you mention.)

Comment: @Wildcard Nicely! Thanks for that! Turns out `mawk` was doing it wrong then, which is odd. I don't know why I used a string literal there...

Comment: (1) Regarding backslashes in `gsub` calls in `awk`, see [The GNU Awk User’s Guide Gory Details — More about ‘\’ and ‘&’ with `sub()`, `gsub()`, and `gensub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html). (2) In your second solution, I believe that you need `b=${a%%:*}`, because the delimiter is (presumably) the *first* colon.  Since the OP says that the text after the colon delimiter is arbitrary, it could include additional colon(s); e.g., ``a\b\c\d:foo:bar``.

Comment: @Scott Good catch, I've updated. And thanks for the reference too!